# Tensorflow: Failing to train wide and deep model on MovieLens Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Based on the Wide and deep tutorial, I´m trying to create a similar example using the MovieLens 1-M Dataset.

So far I came up with this code [enter link description here](https://github.com/CnMr236/Wide_n_deep_MovieLens/blob/master/MovieLensTest.py) (GitHub-Link)

Unfortunately, when running my code it seems like my model is not training:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into /var/folders/jl/_c3j45x14cn1w17jxrxv8t8m0000gn/T/tmp9LPo3i/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.726383, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.59595
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 101 (38.522 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.93759
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 201 (34.042 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.83506
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 301 (35.274 sec)
...
```

Results from evaluation:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
accuracy: 1.0
accuracy/baseline_label_mean: 0.0
accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean: 1.0
auc: 1.0
global_step: 2000
labels/actual_label_mean: 0.0
labels/prediction_mean: 0.0
...
```

Is there something wrong with the features im specifying for the wide and/or deep Models or is there a general mistake in my code?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please write the content in the image you provided directly to the post.

Comment: @Shibli changed it

Answer (score 0):

Your `input_fn` is constant and returns always the same examples, which is why you see the loss going quickly to 0 and staying there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I have to change input_fn in order that its not always returning the same example? Do I need to specify for example a Batchsize?

Comment: Currently your input_fn is always returning the same elements from the dataframe. Try either using [pandas_input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn) or looking at its implementation.